# How can i put my below code in a container

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want that my below component would come in a container but instead of coming in container if is showing like this

[image: incorrect out]

I want this to be in a container

continuous item by item in an vertical manner .

This happens when i use

```
<div class="container my-5">
  <div class="main-container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        //my items list. 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Actually I have made a project of carousel using html css jquery
now i want it to import in my node project. i want to simply copy that div section and paste it in middle of this code and it appears but it's not appearing.

When I run the code below the output is -

[image: actual output]

But i want that is should be in a container. but is it no happening need help.

```js
(function($) {
  var slide = function(ele, options) {
    var $ele = $(ele);

    var setting = {
      speed: 1000,

      interval: 10000,
    };

    $.extend(true, setting, options);

    var states = [{
        $zIndex: 1,
        width: 120,
        height: 150,
        top: 69,
        left: 134,
        $opacity: 1,
      },
      {
        $zIndex: 2,
        width: 130,
        height: 170,
        top: 59,
        left: 0,
        $opacity: 0.1
      },
      {
        $zIndex: 3,
        width: 170,
        height: 218,
        top: 35,
        left: 110,
        $opacity: 1,
      },
      {
        $zIndex: 4,
        width: 250,
        height: 300,
        top: 0,
        left: 263,
        $opacity: 1
      },
      {
        $zIndex: 3,
        width: 170,
        height: 218,
        top: 35,
        left: 470,
        $opacity: 1,
      },
      {
        $zIndex: 2,
        width: 130,
        height: 170,
        top: 59,
        left: 620,
        $opacity: 1,
      },
      {
        $zIndex: 1,
        width: 120,
        height: 150,
        top: 69,
        left: 500,
        $opacity: 1,
      },
    ];

    var $lis = $ele.find("li");
    var timer = null;

    $ele.find(".hi-next").on("click", function() {
      next();
    });
    $ele.find(".hi-prev").on("click", function() {
      states.push(states.shift());
      move();
    });
    $ele
      .on("mouseenter", function() {
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = null;
      });
    // .on("mouseleave", function () {
    //   autoPlay();
    // });

    move();
    autoPlay();

    function move() {
      $lis.each(function(index, element) {
        var state = states[index];
        $(element)
          .css("zIndex", state.$zIndex)
          .finish()
          .animate(state, setting.speed)
          .find("img")
          .css("opacity", state.$opacity);
      });
    }

    function next() {
      states.unshift(states.pop());
      move();
    }

    function autoPlay() {
      timer = setInterval(next, setting.interval);
    }
  };

  $.fn.hiSlide = function(options) {
    $(this).each(function(index, ele) {
      slide(ele, options);
    });

    return this;
  };
})(jQuery);
$(".slide").hiSlide();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

body {
  background-image: url(ur.jpg);
}

h1 {
  margin: 150px auto 30px auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
}

.hi-slide {
  position: relative;
  width: 754px;
  height: 292px;
  margin: 115px auto 0;
}

.hi-slide .hi-next,
.hi-slide .hi-prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: black;
  transition: all 0.6s;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.hi-slide .hi-next:hover,
.hi-slide .hi-prev:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.hi-slide .hi-prev {
  left: -60px;
}

.hi-slide .hi-prev::before {
  content: "<";
}

.hi-slide .hi-next {
  right: -60px;
}

.hi-slide .hi-next::before {
  content: ">";
}

.hi-slide>ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 754px;
  height: 292px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.hi-slide>ul>li {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  left: 377px;
  top: 146px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-color: #333;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* .hi-slide > ul > li > img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
  } */
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<div class="container my-5 mt-2">
  <div class="main-container">
    <div class="mt-2 d-flex justify-content-around">
      <h2 class="text-center">Timeline</h2>
      <div class="slide hi-slide">
        <div class="hi-prev"></div>
        <div class="hi-next"></div>

        <ul>
          <li>
            <div class="card">
              <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1523275335684-37898b6baf30?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8cHJvZHVjdHxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="Img 1" height="150px" />
              <div class="card-body space">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>



                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                <br>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="card">
              <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1505740420928-5e560c06d30e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8M3x8cHJvZHVjdHxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="Img 1" height="140px" />
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>

                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                <br>
                <br>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="card">
              <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1600080972464-8e5f35f63d08?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mjh8fHByb2R1Y3R8ZW58MHx8MHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="Img 1" height="150px" />
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>

                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="card">
              <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1572635196237-14b3f281503f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Nnx8cHJvZHVjdHxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="Img 1" height="150px" />
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>

                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="card">
              <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542291026-7eec264c27ff?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTB8fHByb2R1Y3R8ZW58MHx8MHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="Img 1" height="150px" />
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>

                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>

              </div>

            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="card">
              <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1564466809058-bf4114d55352?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MjJ8fHByb2R1Y3R8ZW58MHx8MHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="Img 1" height="150px" />
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>

                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                <br><br>
                <br>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="card">
              <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1546868871-7041f2a55e12?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTZ8fHByb2R1Y3R8ZW58MHx8MHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="Img 1" height="150px" />
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>

                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="card">
              <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1581235720704-06d3acfcb36f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTN8fHByb2R1Y3R8ZW58MHx8MHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="Img 1" height="90px" />
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p><br/><br><br/></p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. I had to move the hiSlide to the end of the script to make the snippet run. It still gives an error though

Comment: actually it didn't run like this you have to made these file locally and then run. I jus want to put this in a container

Comment: Well, you have an error. 7 states and 8  LIs. You need 7 LIs or add this: `var state = states[index]; if (!state) { console.log("no state for index",index); return}`